# Salesforce Editions and Subscriptions for a Custom Web application

Tags: salesforcedx

I am a beginner and planning to use salesforce for my hostel management system application. When I went through salesforce documentations for my learning and familiarization, I knew that there is salesforce essential, professional and enterprise editions are there as different org and need to have any of these for application development and for deployment.

Here my confusion that, In my application the domain is not related to opportunities, contacts , accounts.. etc. I need entirely a fresh salesforce DX project with totally different tabs. So If I am starting Salesforce DX scratch project, Still Do I need these any of these editions for development and deployment ? Or Can I deploy my fresh project without going these editions?

Because I don't want to bring the default salesforce org objects to my application.  Can anyone please guide me to resolve my confusions or suggest any good documentation to refer?

Answer (score 0):

The "edition" doesn't just have a collection of objects. They have fundamentally different features, such as storage limits per license, API functionality, API limits per day, and so on. Every org, even the no-longer-offered Personal Edition, had Accounts and Contacts built-in. However, if you don't need them, you can create custom profiles that have no access to those CRM objects. In addition, you can get some lower-priced licenses for your users that have minimal/no access to CRM features. You can contact your Sales Associate for more details. As far as which edition is right for you, see the [comparison charts](https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/sales-and-service-cloud/) for the differences, and have a conversation with someone more knowledgeable about Salesforce to determine what each feature does and if you need it for your application.